# How to use ls to ascii sort directory contents with symbols first then alphabetically

Tags: unix, ls

I'd like to use `ls` command to sort a directory but organize the results similar to Windows, with file or directory names beginning with symbols on top -- or like the order in `$ man ascii`.

**Right now I get:**

`$ /bin/ls -al`

```
total 16
drwxrwxr-x.  2 yasi  yasi   4096 Jan  7 13:58 .
drwxrwxrwt. 18 root root 12288 Jan  7 14:50 ..
-rw-rw-r--.  1 yasi  yasi      0 Jan  7 13:23 abc
-rw-rw-r--.  1 yasi  yasi      0 Jan  7 13:23 bac
-rw-rw-r--.  1 yasi  yasi      0 Jan  7 13:23 _bac
-rw-rw-r--.  1 yasi  yasi      0 Jan  7 13:58 ~bbc
-rw-rw-r--.  1 yasi  yasi      0 Jan  7 13:23 #bca
-rw-rw-r--.  1 yasi  yasi      0 Jan  7 13:23 cab
```

**I would like:**

```
drwxrwxr-x.  2 yasi  yasi   4096 Jan  7 13:58 .
drwxrwxrwt. 18 root root 12288 Jan  7 14:50 ..
-rw-rw-r--.  1 yasi  yasi      0 Jan  7 13:23 #bca
-rw-rw-r--.  1 yasi  yasi      0 Jan  7 13:23 _bac
-rw-rw-r--.  1 yasi  yasi      0 Jan  7 13:23 abc
-rw-rw-r--.  1 yasi  yasi      0 Jan  7 13:23 bac
-rw-rw-r--.  1 yasi  yasi      0 Jan  7 13:23 cab
-rw-rw-r--.  1 yasi  yasi      0 Jan  7 13:58 ~bbc
```

Comment: LC_COLLATE  - part of locale affects the ls sort order.  You will have to change your locale settings. The POSIX or C locale sorts in ASCII order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the locale in the shell.  Try the following:

```
export LC_ALL="C"
```

This will sort as per your desire.

You can verify the current settings by using the command `locale`.